# Use Dynamic SQL To Create View From Cursor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I want to iterate the table names that are listed in a table and create one view that has all of the info listed.  I have the cursor set, I have the base of the view set, but how would I modify the syntax to add a UNION ALL statement instead of repeating the Create View statement?

This is the syntax I have:

```
Create Table dbo.tabletoprocess
(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL 
    ,DatabaseName varchar(100) NOT NULL
    ,TablePrefix varchar(25) NOT NULL
    ,ActiveCustomer varchar(50) NOT NULL
)



Insert Into dbo.tabletoprocess (DatabaseName, TablePrefix, ActiveCustomer) VALUES
('arc', 'night91_', 'yes')
,('bell', 'abc123_', 'yes')
,('fed', 'fred13_', 'yes')
,('rea', 'bad12_', 'yes')
,('bva', 'red121_', 'yes')
,('sez', 'bc12_', 'yes')

Declare @dbname varchar(100), @tableprefix varchar(100), @sql nvarchar(max), @fullpre varchar(500)

Declare DB_CURSOR CURSOR FOR

    Select databasename, tableprefix
    FROM tabletoprocess 
    WHERE ActiveCustomer = 'yes'

    OPEN DB_CURSOR
    FETCH NEXT FROM DB_CURSOR INTO @dbname, @tableprefix

    Set @fullpre = @dbname + '.' + @tableprefix

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        Set @sql = 'Create View dbo.Test As 
                    Select *                        
                        FROM OPENQUERY(linkedserver, ''Select op.field1, op.field2, o.field3, a.field4, 
                                                a.field5, a.field6, a.field7, a.field8, a.field9, 
                                                o.field10, o.field11 
                                                FROM '+@fullpre+'orderinfo as op 
                                                LEFT JOIN '+@fullpre+'order as o ON op.oi=o.oi 
                                                LEFT JOIN '+@fullpre+'address as a
                                                ON o.osa_id=a.ai'')';
        Print @sql

         FETCH NEXT FROM DB_CURSOR INTO @dbname, @tableprefix

    END

CLOSE DB_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE DB_CURSOR
```

Comment: Are you trying to use UNION ALL in order to create multiple views with one statement?  If so, that's not what UNION ALL is for.  Or are you trying to create one view for multiple tables?

Comment: @MguerraTorres - one view for multiple tables

Comment: Ahh, then yeah you're good to go.  Just add the UNION ALL between the a.ai and the first single quote at the end.  Your issue is actually getting the additional table names.  You'll have to make the cursor set @sql += ' UNION ALL... '

Comment: and where would my exec @sql statement go?  As it sits currently, each statement printed begins with Create View....

Comment: Use the cursor to keep adding to @sql.  Then after the cursor completes you EXECUTE the sql variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried modifying the `set` command like such:

```
Set @sql = isnull(@sql,'') +
           case when @sql is NULL
                then ' create view dbo.Test as ' 
                else ' union all '
           end +
           'SELECT ...'
```

Obviously (?) the `print @sql` (and `exec @sql`) is issued after the cursor loop has been completed/closed.

---

Here's a sample [fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=41cbd7d7cc95089d8799fb1cd8252060) showing the results:

```
declare @sql varchar(max), @cr char(1)
set @cr = char(10)

Set @sql = isnull(@sql,'') + @cr +
           case when @sql is NULL
                then 'create view dbo.Test as ' 
                else 'union all '
           end + @cr +
           'SELECT x from mytable1 ...'

Set @sql = isnull(@sql,'') + @cr +
           case when @sql is NULL
                then 'create view dbo.Test as ' 
                else 'union all '
           end + @cr +
           'SELECT y from mytable2 ...'

Set @sql = isnull(@sql,'') + @cr +
           case when @sql is NULL
                then 'create view dbo.Test as ' 
                else 'union all '
           end + @cr +
           'SELECT z from mytable3 ...'

print @sql
```

And the results of running the above:

```
create view dbo.Test as 
SELECT x from mytable1 ...
union all 
SELECT y from mytable2 ...
union all 
SELECT z from mytable3 ...
```

Comment: If I modify my syntax to be such as above nothing is printed from my print @sql statement?

Comment: ah, forgot MS SQL doesn't like to append null values to non-null values; have updated my answer (+ `isnull(@sql,'')`) ... see if that works now?

Comment: That is printing the Create View statement before each iteration

Comment: You'll need to show us the code you've written; I've added a dbfiddle to my answer that shows the proposed code working as desired.

Comment: The code I am using is in my OP or you can view it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1c136/1

Comment: Have you tried the code on your own system?  there appears to be some problems with how `sqlfiddle` operates; I copied your code over to dbfiddle and it works as expected, though it wouldn't hurt to add some cr's to make it a little prettier :) [your code on dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=451c0252f29d39cce6d77f519316d8a3); each iteration through the loop **is** adding a 'union all select ...' to @sql; obviously in your final solution you only want to see/execute @sql once so as previously mentioned, run the `print/exec` **after** the loop has been completed

Comment: Yes, the dbfiddle produces the same issue.  I want ONE view with all of the tables, if you look at the dbfiddle above each different Select statement has the Create View statement above it - which is not what I am afte.r

Comment: take a closer look at your code ... you're `print`ing for each pass through the loop, so on each pass you get an additional 'union all select ...` added to @sql; what you want is to `print` **once** after the loop; I've moved the `print` outside the loop to show it **is** working as desired : http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9fc5373adde37e02b1864e1a573d5269; my point being that if you're going to `print` on each pass through the loop then you're going to see `create view ...` displayed for each pass through the loop, but you'll also see an additional `union all select ...`

Comment: Ah, that covered it.  Thank you for your time and patience!